# ¿Cómo se realiza este recorte o forma en css?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, web

[image: cómo se hace ese tipo de recorte y que la imagen qeude subre el degradado en esa forma?]

Me gustaria saber como realizar ese diseño de formas y superposicion de la imagen

Comment: Puedes realizarlo mediante SVGs (hay muchas herramientas online para generarlos sin escribir código) y jugar con CSS para posicionar el contenido.

Comment: Aquí te dejo un tutorial bastante bueno(en inglés): https://youtu.be/OjIxscGV-Qg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muy fácil, todo depende del comportamiento que quieras lograr con la foto y si necesitas que esté en el html o no.

Lo puedes hacer con una estructura como esta:

Al banner, solo basta con colocarle la altura y el `overflow: hidden;` para la parte de la foto que no queremos que salga.

Puedes posicionar de forma absoluta el **`container_img`** en una esquina que recorte incluso más de la mitad del cuadro. A este le aplicas el fondo gradiente y el box-shadow. Así:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container_img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -45%;
  right: -30%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2em #edfdfd;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #39fee0,
    #51d7f9
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> 
  <section class="container_img">
    <figure class="media_img">
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Una vez ubicado este cuadro en esta parte, lo puedes rotar con un `transform: rotateZ(angulo_que_quieras)` y ya tienes más o menos la forma armada, si no fuera por el gradiente, de una vez podrías ubicar la imagen dentro de este elemento como fondo y hacerlo todo por `box-shadow`.

Lo siguiente que debes hacer es darle un `border-radius` al `media-img` lo ubicas más al centro y le colocas un `overflow: hidden;`.

Ahora crea un pseudo elemento dentro del `media-img`y a este le colocas la imagen de fondo.

Por último, corrige la rotación del `container-img`, es decir, si le pusiste `transform: rotateZ(-15deg)`, acá le pones: `transform: rotateZ(15deg)` y mediante modificar el `top`, `left`, `height` y `width`lo ubicas en una posición donde no se vea el fondo gradiente.

Te recomiendo unas medidas como estas:

```
.media_img::before{
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  top: 10%;
  left: -10%;
}
```

Y listo, acá una demo funcional:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container_img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -45%;
  right: -30%;
  transform: rotateZ(-14deg);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2em #edfdfd;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #39fee0,
    #51d7f9
  );
}

.media_img{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 2em;
  background: white;
  top: -2em;
  left: 2em;
} 

.media_img::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: rotateZ(14deg);
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  top: 10%;
  left: -10%;
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=7');
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> 
  <section class="container_img">
    <figure class="media_img">
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Ahora, todo depende de lo que quieras lograr, porque realizar esa forma no tan "cuadrada" de recorte o mascara no se puede aún con las herramientas de css normales, incluso te recomendaría hacerlo media `clip-path`pero combinándolo con una forma `SVG`, ya aún no se pueden hacer bordes redondeados en esa forma o directamente exportar un png con fondo transparente, donde solo dejas ver en una esquina el fondo y lo ubicas en todo el fondo, antes de la imagen blanca.

Lo otro es que directamente pintes el SVG dentro del contenedor y lo ubiques dentro de la imagen que tiene la foto, de esa manera, siempre podrás usarlo como máscara y/o editarlo vía código. Eso sí, antes asegurate de cambiar el **`preserveAspectRatio="none"`** para que permita estirarlo o econgerlo.

Ejemplo:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner{
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container_svg{
  position: absolute;  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.media_img{
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=7');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.svg_img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> 
  <figure class="container_svg media_img">
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1365.11 768" class="svg_img" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="a" x1="714.13" x2="1185.51" y1="215.09" y2="797.18" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#33ffe4"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#74b4fc"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g data-name="Capa 2">
        <g data-name="Capa 1">
          <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h910.31L604 432l21 89 740.06 170.58L1365 768H0V0z"/>
          <path fill="#33ffe4" d="M1365 768L590.46 632.41C462.46 610 411 454.09 500.41 359.84L842 0h90L584 492l781.11 171.88" opacity=".13"/>
          <path fill="url(#a)" d="M932 0h-43L577 377.82c-57.22 69.34-20.1 174.71 68 192.85L1365 719l.11-55.12-685.3-164.63a51.33 51.33 0 0 1-30.61-78.54z"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  
  
  </figure>
</div>
```

Sí no es lo que buscabas o no entiendes algo, no te inhibas y dejame tu comentario. Éxitos!

Comment: Muchas gracias Edgar :D